# How can i make each column equal to each other in bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Hello everyone I am trying to make the width of my colums equal to each other. I want all of the colums to be the same width except for the columns update and delete. Those two should stay the same as they are right now.

I am using bootstrap 4.5.2

**This is my bootstrap table**

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-responsive-sm table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>TimeSlot</th>
                <th>Room</th>
                <th>Attendees</th>
                <th>update</th>
                <th>delete</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

                <tbody>
                    <tr class="table">
                        <td class="table">Date</td>
                        <td class="table">Time</td>
                        <td class="table">Room</td>
                        <td class="table">invitee</td>
                        <td class="table" style="display: none">reservationid</td>
                        <td class="table" style="display: none">invitedby</td>
                        <td class="table" style="display: none">workspace</td>
                        <td class="table">
                            <a onclick="onUpdate()" style="color: #007bff; cursor: pointer"> <i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                        </td>
                        <td class="table">
                            <a onclick="onDelete()" style="color: #007bff; cursor: pointer"> <i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            }
    </table>
```

**Here is my bootstrap table in the browser**
[image: Here is my bootstrap table in the browser]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to differentiate somehow your data columns from your command columns and apply your CSS just for your data columns:

```css
td.table:not(.command) {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 15% !important;
}
```

```html
<table class="table table-bordered table-responsive-sm table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>TimeSlot</th>
                <th>Room</th>
                <th>Attendees</th>
                <th>update</th>
                <th>delete</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

                <tbody>
                    <tr class="table">
                        <td class="table">Date</td>
                        <td class="table">Time</td>
                        <td class="table">Room</td>
                        <td class="table">invitee</td>
                        <td class="table" style="display: none">reservationid</td>
                        <td class="table" style="display: none">invitedby</td>
                        <td class="table" style="display: none">workspace</td>
                        <td class="table command">
                            <a onclick="onUpdate()" style="color: #007bff; cursor: pointer"> <i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                        </td>
                        <td class="table command">
                            <a onclick="onDelete()" style="color: #007bff; cursor: pointer"> <i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            }
    </table>
```

Comment: Putting the width on 25% instead of 15% works great. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the table class from the HTML , then switch to a [`table-layout:fixed;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/table-layout) and finally set a `width` as [`min-content`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/width) for the last 2 cells via [`:nth-last-child()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-last-child) .

**edit `min-content` fails with chrome ... use a static width around 5em .**

all together it could be *(run snippet in fullpage to see last two cells not growing)*:

```css
table.fixed {
  table-layout: fixed;
}

table.fixed tr> :nth-last-child(-n+2) {
  /*width: min-content; fails with chrome */
  width:5em;
  color:crimson;/* see me ;) */
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.1/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table class="table table-bordered table-responsive-sm table-hover fixed"><!-- added a custom class named fixed -->
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Date</th>
      <th>TimeSlot</th>
      <th>Room</th>
      <th>Attendees</th>
      <th>update</th>
      <th>delete</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr class="table">
      <td class="">Date</td>
      <td class="">Time</td>
      <td class="">Room</td>
      <td class="">invitee</td>
      <td class="" style="display: none">reservationid</td>
      <td class="" style="display: none">invitedby</td>
      <td class="" style="display: none">workspace</td>
      <td class="">
        <a onclick="onUpdate()" style="color: #007bff; cursor: pointer"> <i class="far fa-edit" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
      </td>
      <td class="">
        <a onclick="onDelete()" style="color: #007bff; cursor: pointer"> <i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i></a></a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
```

Comment: This works great on firefox but in chrome it seperates the column update and delete. And the 2 columns are shown on top of each other for some reason. Also when I run your snippet in chrome the same thing is happening but in firefox your snippet works fine.

Comment: @John thanks for the feed back, then i guess width is to be set around 5em to fit the words update/delete length ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use bootstrap's built-in classes for this if you use flexbox. HTML below.

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-responsive-sm table-hover">
    <thead class="d-flex">
        <tr class="d-flex col-10 pl-0 pr-0">
            <th class="col-3">Date</th>
            <th class="col-3">TimeSlot</th>
            <th class="col-3">Room</th>
            <th class="col-3">Attendees</th>
        </tr>
        <tr class="d-flex col-2 pl-0 pr-0">
            <th class="col-6">update</th>
            <th class="col-6">delete</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody class="d-flex">
        <tr class="d-flex col-10 pl-0 pr-0">
            <td class="col-3">Date</td>
            <td class="col-3">Time</td>
            <td class="col-3">Room</td>
            <td class="col-3">invitee</td>
            <!-- <td class="table col" style="display: none">reservationid</td>
            <td class="table col" style="display: none">invitedby</td>
            <td class="table col" style="display: none">workspace</td> -->
        </tr>
        <tr class="d-flex col-2 pl-0 pr-0">
            <td class="col-6">
                <a onclick="onUpdate()" style="color: #007bff; cursor: pointer">
                    <i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i
                ></a>
            </td>
            <td class="col-6">
                <a onclick="onDelete()" style="color: #007bff; cursor: pointer">
                    <i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i
                ></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: For some reason this works only on firefox for me and not on chrome

Comment: That's weird because I tested it with Chrome. Try it in incognito mode and let me know if it's still the same.

Comment: yeah still the same problem

Comment: Is there any reason you're not using Bootstrap 5.0.0? When I switched to 4.5.0, I got your same problem, but it works fine with 5.

Comment: Just edited my answer and it works, though I wouldn't say it's exactly pretty. The pro of it though is it uses only built in bootstrap classes instead of writing your own css.

Comment: I am halfway through my project and it would be really hard to change bootstrap versions right now. thanks for the new adjustments I will try it out